# Nginx plus JWT token validation goes in error when is needed a proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, jwt

I am having a problem using Nginx Plus to verify a JWT Token.
It works if there's a return statement but goes in error if there's a proxy pass.

```
location = /_jwks_uri {
   internal;
   proxy_pass        https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx/discovery/v2.0/keys;
}

location /test" {
    auth_jwt             "closed site";
        #auth_jwt_key_cache   1h;
        auth_jwt_key_request /_jwks_uri;
            
        auth_request /auth_client;
        satisfy all;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_keepalive 10;
        proxy_pass https://httpbin.org;
}
```

I am usign Azure AD as Identity provider.
The error that i get is:

```
JWT RS validation failed kid:"-xyxyxyxyxyxyxyyxyx" (SSL: error:04091068:rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:bad signature) while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /test/ok HTTP/1.1", host: "nginx.local", referrer: "http://localhost:3000/"
```

do you know which can be the reason ?